# UrlRewriter.net exclusive regex rules

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I am trying to add some rewrite rules using [UrlRewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/) to my ASP.NET web app. The problem is that I am a Regex newbie, and [provided examples](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/conditions/url-match) are pretty elementary.

My question is: how do I differentiate urls which contain GET query parameters?

I.e., if I add this rule:

```
<rewrite url="~/([.+])" to="~/$1.aspx" />
```

It will rewrite `www.example.com/products` to `www.example.com/products.aspx`, but it will also rewrite `www.example.com/products?id=1` to `www.example.com/products?id=1.aspx`.

Problem actually only happens when using a login control, since it creates an url similar to `www.example.com/login?returnUrl=/members`, and I am not sure how to rewrite it.

What I would like is:

- to rewrite `www.ex.com/test` to `www.ex.com/test.aspx`, and
- to rewrite `www.ex.com/test?page=dummy` to `www.ex.com/test.aspx?page=dummy.aspx`

Thanks a lot!

**[edit]** And btw I still haven't figured how to turn on console debugging for UrlRewriter. I have added the "register logger" section to the config file, but VS output windows shows nothing. That would be helpful, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex for the match:

```
"~/([^\?]+)(.*)?"
```

This way you match everything *until* the question mark - one or more chars that aren't a question mark.

Then $1 holds the path part, and $2 everything from the "?" until the end of the URL.

Notice the question mark after the second grouping parentheses - this means that you don't require that part, so `www.ex.com/test` will also work.

Comment: This solved the problem in my question, but I also had to do some rewriting in `Global.Application_EndRequest` handler, because login control sees rewritten urls under the hood, so links were usually messed up during webform POSTs.